# Searching string with special characters in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

I want to search values having special characters such as `" $ / . @ > "` in a document.

Lets consider, I've myKey with values like `"test$australia", "test$austria", "test$belgium",  "green.africa".`

I want to search values with `'.*$aus.*',`

For example,

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : /.*$aus.*/i });
```

OR

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : { '$regex' : '.*$aus.*','$options' : 'i' });
```

Above queries dont work , how should I form query?
I'm using MongoDB 2.4.1.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to escape `$` by `\`:

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : /.*\$aus.*/i }); 
// OR
db.myCollection.find({myKey: { $regex: '.*\\$aus.*', $options: 'i'}})
```

Comment: Could you please remove qr operator which is not needed in console.. I edited in the question also. It did worked.

Comment: Also how can I achieve the same with REGEX option.

Comment: You have to double the backslash in the regex string in the mongo json query: `db.myCollection.find({myKey: { $regex: '.*\\$aus.*', $options: 'i'}})`

Comment: `db.mycollection_name.find({ "name" : { "$regex" : "Corp Limited \\( Group\\)", "$options" : "i" }},{name:1})`
Worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Escape all regex special characters:

```
  name.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
```

Create a query with regex and option "i" (ignore case):

```
  const databaseQuery = { name: new RegExp(`${req.query.name}`, 'i') };
```

Perform a search with a query:

```
  db.collection.find(databaseQuery)
```

Note: don't forget to create indexes for the fields that you will search through. Indexing fields increases the speed of your regex queries.
In my case for my 'name' field it would be like this:

```
  db.collection.createIndex({ name: "text" })
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
db.myCollection.find({myKey:{ $regex:new RegExp('^' + 'test$australia'.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + '$', 'i')}})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
db.test.insert({word: 'hai('});
db.test.insert({word: 'jana'});
```

Output be like that :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f27fb71d843581261433c6"), "word" : "hai(" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f27ffe1d843581261433c8"), "word" : "jana" }
```

Note : Want the special char row alone so

```
db.test.find({word:{$regex:"\\("}});
```

Output be like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f27fb71d843581261433c6"), "word" : "hai(" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex-escape. It is a good library for escaping special characters to be used in regular expressions

```
    var RegexEscape = require("regex-escape");

    let keyword = RegexEscape("{#/}");
    // => \{#\/\}


   db.myCollection.find({ myKey : { '$regex' : keyword, '$options' : 'mi' });
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java Equivalent for https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322010/8208083 is as follows:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\.\\*\\+\\?\\^\\${}\\(\\)|\\]\\[\\\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(searchKeyword);
searchKeyword = m.replaceAll("\\\\$0");
```

This is useful when you need to pass the search keyword in the @Query annotation of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Define the search key under the `re.escape` function that will resolve the issue for special character regex.

```
{search_field: {"$regex": '{}.*'.format(re.escape(search_key)),"$options": 'i'}}
```