# mongodb won't take $ as index in update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I udpated my mongo instance from version 2.4 to 3.4 and all of my update queries stopped working where I was passing $ as index.
If I pass static 0 or 1 in the query it works fine, but earlier syntax of $ won't work at all.

Below is my query :

```
db.collection('users').update({"email": "u1@u1.com","companies":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"1487006991927"}}}, 
    {
        $set: {
            "companies.$.details" : {"company_name":"hey updated"}
        }
    });
```

Response that I get :

```
{ result: { _t: 'UpdateResponse', ok: 1, n: 1, nModified: 1 },
```

This worked perfectly while I was on mongo vesrion 2.4 but not anymore. I can't always pass static 0 / 1 or index, what is the right way to do it ?

Also to note : Response says that 1 record was modified, but nothing was modified actually.

```
{
    "_id": "589aa3509a248a3d7a01b784",
    "businessAndPersonal": "true",
    "companies": [
        {
            "details": {
                "company_name": "afsfhey updated"
            },
            "locations": [],
            "websites": [],
            "id": "1487006991927"
        },
        {
            "details": {
                "company_name": "hey updated"
            },
            "locations": [],
            "websites": [],
            "id": "1487007435955"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you _sure_ there were no modifications? I don't think mongo would lie to you like that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes. there wasn't any change. I've almost tried it 10 times. As said above if I mention 0 / 1 instead of $ then it works fine. it just won't work with $

Comment: Tried it, works for me. http://pastebin.com/3aJmujKt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching string with special characters in MongoDB document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560291/searching-string-with-special-characters-in-mongodb-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for my own question

I am using CosmosDB mongodb service as far they doesn't support positional operator of mongodb

[Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20091454-positional-array-update-via-query-support) is link that has discussion on **positional array update via '$'** query support