# Search in Mongodb passing variable (search terms) from API

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I am using Nodejs and Mongodb. I've written an API to return documents against searched property, I've managed to return all the results containing the searched terms. This is the code that I am using

```js
collection.find({ "phone": new RegExp(req.params.phone, 'i') }, function (err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
```

Everything seems to work fine but when I search with string starting with `+` I get the following exception

`Invalid regular expression: /.*+.*/: Nothing to repeat`.

This seems to be a problem with what I am creating my `regex expression` and I am not so good with `regex`.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape the `+` character with `\` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16560838/2012407)) as it is used in regex to repeat a pattern at least once.

- `.*` means repeat anything 0 times or more
- `.+` means repeat anything 1 time or more
- `.*+` breaks

hope it solves your current problem, but also note that your regex is very loose and can capture anything even special chars & whitespaces.