# Getting error during regular expression search when string having parentheses in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I am getting the following error while search with MongoDB document using regular expression.

> Error::

```
err SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /PU1-PCMB BOYS (/: Unterminated group
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at EdQartProductsService.getProductsByFilter (/home/anil/Desktop/new/17Feb/local/edqart-store-setup-api/src/services/products.service.js:111:36)
```

I am explaining my query below.

```
const nameOrSku = _.get(req.body.filters, 'nameOrSku', '');
if(!_.isEmpty(nameOrSku)) {
    const nameArr = [
        { 'ProductName': { $regex: new RegExp(nameOrSku), $options: 'i' } },
        { 'SKU': { $regex: new RegExp(nameOrSku), $options: 'i' } }
    ];
    _.set(filters, '$or', nameArr);
}
```

Here Its working for simple string case. If `nameOrSku=PU1-PCMB BOYS (KANNADA) KIT` which is actually `ProductName` present inside MongoDB document then its throwing this king of issue. For any simple text its working fine. Here I need to resolve this kind of issue and match also if staring has any special charcter.

Comment: It's because you need to escape out the parenthesis by using `\(` instead of `(`

Comment: How it can be handled because all search text may not have the `()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50853031/3832970 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322010/3832970