# why java mongodb driver update a value can't start with $

Tags: java, mongodb

```java
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

Bson filters = Filters.eq("id", 123456);

List<Bson> bsonArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
bsonArrayList.add(Updates.set("income", "$300k"));

UpdateResult updateResult = mongoExe.updateOne(filters, bsonArrayList, options);
```

The field name is `income`, value is `$200k`. It can't update until I delete the `$`

`bsonArrayList.add(Updates.set("income", "300k"));`

how can I do to make it ?

why java mongodb driver update a value can't start with `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [literal](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#-literal--aggregation-):

```java
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

...
bsonArrayList.add(Updates.set("income", eq("$literal", "$300k")));
```

or

```java
bsonArrayList.add(Updates.set("income", new Document("$literal", "$300k")));
```

`eq` is just a container (or shorthand for `Document`) in this case.

Comment: Is the eq belong to Filters?

Comment: what do you mean? ---->eq is just a container (or shorthand for Document) in this case.

Comment: Is Anywhere error ? It didn't work when i use   -->         bsonArrayList.add(Updates.set("income", new Document("$literal", "$300k")));

Comment: `new Document` also works with me. `eq` is part of `Filters`. Please use latest mondodb drvier `4.8.2`

Answer (score 0):

The $ is a special character in MongoDB, [see here for a description](https://www.stevebreese.com/MongoDB-Using-Regex-for-Pattern-Matching).

You can fix it by escaping the character, [see here for how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560291/searching-string-with-special-characters-in-mongodb-document)

Comment: thanks!   But it maybe just apply to mongo select SQL. I am using  java mongo driver update function